# Glue JSON serialization and athena query, return full record each field

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I've been trying for a long time, through Glue's crawlers, to recognize .jsons from my S3, to be queried in Athena. But after different changes in settings, the best result I got, is still wrong.

Glue's crawler even recognizes the column structure of my .json, however, when queried in Athena, it sets up the columns found, but throws all items in the same line, one item for each column, as in images below.

My Classifier setting is "$[*]".

The .json data structure

```json
[

    { "id": "TMA.fid--4f6e8018_18596f01b4f\_-5e3a", "airspace_p": 1061, "codedistv1": "SFC", "fid": 299 },
    { "id": "TMA.fid--4f6e8018_18596f01b4f\_-5e39", "airspace_p": 408, "codedistv1": "STD", "fid": 766 },
    { "id": "TMA.fid--4f6e8018_18596f01b4f\_-5e38", "airspace_p": 901, "codedistv1": "STD", "fid": 806 },
...

]
```

Configuration result in Glue:
[Configuration result in Glue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0hT9.png)

Result in Athena from this table:
[Result in Athena from this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwjUs.png)

I already tried different .json structures, different classifiers, changed and added the JsonSerde

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the data source, use the JSON lines format instead, then run the Glue crawler without any custom classifier.

```json
{"id": "TMA.fid--4f6e8018_18596f01b4f_-5e3a","airspace_p": 1061,"codedistv1": "SFC","fid": 299}
{"id": "TMA.fid--4f6e8018_18596f01b4f_-5e39","airspace_p": 408,"codedistv1": "STD","fid": 766}
{"id": "TMA.fid--4f6e8018_18596f01b4f_-5e38","airspace_p": 901,"codedistv1": "STD","fid": 806}
```

Cause of your issue is that [Athena doesn't support custom JSON classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/troubleshooting-athena.html).